# Exodus points for discussion?

Tags: history, commentaries, shemot-exodus, archaeology

I have a few questions abou the Exodus.

1. Is there any way to know in which era or year the Exodus took place?
2. And do we take Pharaoh to mean Pharaoh or could it be any family member, vice or under king, landlord or ruler in Egypt?
3. Is there a possibility that although HaShem made Moshe know that He was the G-d of the Hebrews (Ivrim) and Avram is called the 'Ivri' , this wasn't the name they were known by or called by the other nations/people?

This could explain why it's so hard to find archaelogical proof or sources to support the event for those who doubt it even happened.

Comment: The Exodus had to happen at least 40 years before 1213 BCE, since the Mernepteh Stele lists "Israel" with the determinative sign for a clan/tribe/people. It's a victory stele listing stuff he allegedly conquered during one of his campaigns--it doesn't state an exact date for the Exodus, but it is a clue as to it's historicity and approximate time, and it shows that "Israel" wasn't an established town or nation, but they were there in the Land by that time. Here's the Wiki - https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Merneptah_Stele

Comment: In your question, are you asking specifically for non-Torah based sources, or would sefer hadoros or and of the gemaras that say a date be enough for you?

Comment: @Uber_Chacham what do you mean with non-Torah sources? I would like to know how the date for was determined based on Torah explanation as the commentators often do in the Talmud and other writings which are Torah related. Does this help to answer your question? So for me any answer from books like you mention would do

Answer (score 3):

The Seder Olam Zuta (the basic Jewish book of chronology, compiled just after the sealing of the Talmud) says in Perek Rishon, Halacha Daled,

משנולד יצחק אבינו עד שיצאו ישראל ממצרים ארבה מאות שנה) **היא שנת שני אלפים ארבה מאות ארבעים ושמונה** ליצירה (From the time Yitzchak was born until the the time the Jews left Egypt was four hundred years,) which was in 2448 counting from the creation of the world (3330 years ago; i.e. 1312 BCE).

Comment: If you want more sources than just this please comment; there are numerous ways to count, such as that the verse by the building of the first temple counts the years between then and the Exodus, the first temple stood for 420 years, then there were 70 years until the building of the second temple, which then stood for 410 years, and then was destroyed by the Romans on 70 C.E.. Again, if you want more ways to count it, please comment.

Comment: if they show different answers please do post them.

Comment: No, they're all the same date.

Comment: Better source than the one I quoted!

Comment: I'm having trouble with the formatting and parenthesis again, would you mind fixing it once again? Thanks

Answer (score 1):

According to [Ohr Somayach](https://ohr.edu/special/misc/timeline.htm) the Exodus took place in the Jewish year 2448 corresponding to 1312 BCE.

Ohr Somayach mentions [“Thutmose III?”](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thutmose_III) as the King.

Comment: Are you sure you did the math right? We're in 5778 now, so it was exactly 3330 years ago - shouldn't that be 1312 BCE?